# Setting control visibility is UpdatePanel Load event

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a question: in my web application I have an UpdatePanel. In this UpdatePanel I have some controls and I want to set their visibility in UpdatePanel Load event.

I do it in the following way:

**Default.aspx:**

`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" OnLoad="Sub_UpdatePanel_OnLoad" UpdateMode="Conditional">`

**Default.aspx.vb**

`Protected Sub Sub_UpdatePanel_OnLoad()`

```
    LinkButton1.Visible = True
    LinkButton2.Visible = False
```

End Sub

And that doesn't work. I tried to add UpdatePanel.Update() in code behind, that helped but completelly crashed my jQuery code.

Can you help me with it? I'm sure that the solution is quite simple!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the controls visiblity on Page_Load instead.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         Button1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will Page Load event occur on every UpdatePanel Update?

Comment: Yes, Page_Load will occur every time the page updates. If you want this code to run on every update though, take out the !Page.IsPostBack condition.